# error in values in a new column dataframe with R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe :

```
    word            positive.polarity       negative.polarity 
1 interesting                 1                 0                         
2      boring                 0                 1
```

which contains words and their polarity  (sentiment analysis context).
I try to add another column called positive.ponderate.polarity which contains these value (based on positive.polarity column) :

```
The pseudo code : 


if context(word) in booster_words then 
  if context(word) in negation_words
      positive.ponderate.polarity <- positive.polarity / 3
  else 
      positive.ponderate.polarity <- positive.polarity * 3
  end if
end if
```

The R code function :

```
contextValue <- function(context){
     ifelse(any(unlist(strsplit(context, " ")) %in% booster_words), ifelse(any(unlist(strsplit(context, " ")) %in% negation_word), subDF$positive.polarity / 3, subDF$positive.polarity * 3),55)
 }         

 subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- sapply(context, contextValue)
```

I get   this result :

```
         word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                           3
2      boring                 0                 1                           3
```

which is erronous

The correct result is

```
         word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                           3
2      boring                 0                 1                           **0**
```

The list of booster words and negation words are below :

```
booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as", "so")
negative_words <- c("no", "ever", "not")
```

Can you help me please to resolve the mysterious problem?

Thank you

Comment: what are your booster words and negatiion word?

Comment: But I did a new question. I dont know where is the problem

Comment: @CarlBoneri Ok thank you , i just create a new post here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513672/error-with-a-column-dataframe-with-r