# Error with a column dataframe with R

Tags: r

I have a problem that has blocked me for 2 days, hope that I can find here a solution:

I create a dataframe  which contains a list of words and their positive and negative polarities for sentiment analysis task.

```
  word         positive.polarity       negative.polarity 
1 interesting                 1                 0                          
2      boring                 0                 1
```

For each word I extract its context which is  a set of 3 preceding words.

I have always  a list of booster words :

```
-booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as", "so")
-negative_words <- c("not", "rien", "ni", "aucun", "nul", "jamais", "pas", "non plus", "sans")
```

I would like to create a new column positive.ponderate.polarity which contains positive polarity value devided per 3 if there in a booster and negative word in the context, and multiplied per 3 if there is only booster word in the context (there is ni negative word in context).

When I run with this sentence :

```
"The course was so interesting, but the professor was not boring"
```

I get this data frame :

```
  word positive.polarity negative.polarity       positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                   0.3333333
2      boring                 0                 1                   0.0000000
```

BUT I have to find as result this dataframe :

```
 word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                   3
2      boring                 0                 1                   0.0000000
```

Here is the code :

```
calcPolarity <- function(sentiment_DF,sentences){
    booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as", "so")
    negative_words <- c("not", "rien", "ni", "aucun", "nul", "jamais", "pas", "non plus", "sans")
    reduce_words <- c("peu", "presque", "moins", "seulement")
    # pre-allocate the polarity result vector with size = number of sentences
    polarity <- rep.int(0,length(sentences))

    # loop per sentence
    for(i in 1:length(polarity)){
        sentence <- sentences[i]

        # separate each sentence in words using regular expression 
        wordsOfASentence <- unlist(regmatches(sentence,gregexpr("[[:word:]]+",sentence,perl=TRUE)))

        # get the rows of sentiment_DF corresponding to the words in the sentence using match
        # N.B. if a word occurs twice, there will be two equal rows 
        # (but I think it's correct since in this way you count its polarity twice)
        subDF <- sentiment_DF[match(wordsOfASentence,sentiment_DF$word,nomatch = 0),]


        # Find (number) of matching word. 
        wordOfInterest <- wordsOfASentence[which(wordsOfASentence %in% levels(sentiment_DF$word))]  # No multigrepl, so working with duplicates instead. eg interesting
        regexOfInterest <- paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){0,3}", wordOfInterest, "(\\s[^\\s]+){0,3}")

        # extract a context of 3 words before the word in the dataframe
        context <-  stringr::str_extract(sentence, regexOfInterest)
        names(context) <- wordOfInterest  # Helps in forloop

        print(context)
        if(any(unlist(strsplit(context, " ")) %in% booster_words))

        {
            print(booster_words)
            if(any(unlist(strsplit(context, " ")) %in% negative_words))

            {
                subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity / 3

            }
            else 
            {
                subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity * 3

            }
        }



        # Debug option
        print(subDF)

        # calculate the total polarity of the sentence and store in the vector
        polarity[i] <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) - sum(subDF$negative.ponderate.polarity)

    }
    return(polarity)
}

sentiment_DF <- data.frame(word=c('interesting','boring','pretty'),
                           positive.polarity=c(1,0,1),
                           negative.polarity=c(0,1,0))
sentences <- c("The course was so interesting, but the professor was not boring")
result <- calcPolarity(sentiment_DF,sentences)
```

Usage :

```
result <- calcPolarity(sentiment_DF,sentences)
                interesting                      boring 
"course was so interesting"  "professor was not boring" 
[1] "more"   "enough" "a lot"  "as"     "so"    
         word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                   0.3333333
2      boring                 0                 1                   0.0000000
```

**EDIT:**

```
 calcPolarity <- function(sentiment_DF,sentences){
     booster_words <- c("more","enough", "a lot", "as", "so")
     negative_words <- c("not", "rien", "ni", "aucun", "nul", "jamais", "pas", "non plus", "sans")
     reduce_words <- c("peu", "presque", "moins", "seulement")
     # pre-allocate the polarity result vector with size = number of sentences
     polarity <- rep.int(0,length(sentences))

     # loop per sentence
     for(i in 1:length(polarity)){
         sentence <- sentences[i]

         # separate each sentence in words using regular expression 
        wordsOfASentence <- unlist(regmatches(sentence,gregexpr("[[:word:]]+",sentence,perl=TRUE)))

         # get the rows of sentiment_DF corresponding to the words in the sentence using match
         # N.B. if a word occurs twice, there will be two equal rows 
         # (but I think it's correct since in this way you count its polarity twice)
         subDF <- sentiment_DF[match(wordsOfASentence,sentiment_DF$word,nomatch = 0),]


         # Find (number) of matching word. 
         wordOfInterest <- wordsOfASentence[which(wordsOfASentence %in% levels(sentiment_DF$word))]  # No multigrepl, so working with duplicates instead. eg interesting
         regexOfInterest <- paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){0,3}", wordOfInterest, "(\\s[^\\s]+){0,3}")

         # extract a context of 3 words before the word in the dataframe
        context <-  stringr::str_extract(sentence, regexOfInterest)
         names(context) <- wordOfInterest  # Helps in forloop

         print(context)
         for(i in 1:length(context)){
             if(any(unlist(strsplit(context[i], " ")) %in% booster_words))

             {
                 print(booster_words)
                 if(any(unlist(strsplit(context[i], " ")) %in% negative_words))

                 {
                     subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity + 4

                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity + 9

                 }
             }
         }



         # Debug option
         print(subDF)

         # calculate the total polarity of the sentence and store in the vector
         polarity[i] <- sum(subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity) - sum(subDF$negative.ponderate.polarity)

    }
     return(polarity)
 }

 sentiment_DF <- data.frame(word=c('interesting','boring','pretty'),
                            positive.polarity=c(1,0,1),
                            negative.polarity=c(0,1,0))
 sentences <- c("The course was interesting, but the professor was not so boring")
 result <- calcPolarity(sentiment_DF,sentences)
```

I get this result :

```
       word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                           5
2      boring                 0                 1                           4
```

But it is incorrest, I must have this result

```
      word positive.polarity negative.polarity positive.ponderate.polarity
1 interesting                 1                 0                           1
2      boring                 0                 1                           4
```

Any idea please?

Comment: I don't know why you rank my question in -1 ?? I respect all the rules of SO , I post my code, my question, .:/

Comment: Why -1 point to my post? I respect the SO rules...?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you were searching through both sets of proceeding words in your function i.e., the positive and negative for interesting and boring.

I added a for loop to the `calcPolarity` function before you run through the if statements that worked for me:

```
for(i in 1:length(context)){
  if(any(unlist(strsplit(context[i], " ")) %in% booster_words))

  {
    print(booster_words)
    if(any(unlist(strsplit(context[i], " ")) %in% negative_words))

    {
      subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity / 3

    }
    else 
    {
      subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity <- subDF$positive.polarity * 3

    }
  }
}
```

Which gave the desired results:

```
     word positive.polarity negative.polarity    positive.ponderate.polarity
  1 interesting                 1                 0                            3
  2      boring                 0                 1                            0
```

**EDIT:**

The issue is that you were not properly indexing the values you wanted to replace. Because you didn't specify the the row of the positive ponderate polarity it was altering the entire column.

The below edit should work to do what you need but there is almost certainly a more efficient way to do this.

```
for(j in 1:length(context)){
  if(any(unlist(strsplit(context[j], " ")) %in% booster_words)) {
    print(booster_words)
    if(any(unlist(strsplit(context[j], " ")) %in% negative_words)){
      subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity[j] <- subDF$positive.polarity[j] + 4
    }
    else 
    {
      subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity[j] <- subDF$positive.polarity[j] + 9
    }
  }
  else {
    subDF$positive.ponderate.polarity[j] <- subDF$positive.polarity[j]
  }
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much, you save my life :)

Comment: No problem :) glad I could help

Comment: @ GarAust89 It seems that there another problem. I edit my first post